# VBA Excel won't copy data to sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the data from a hand full of CSV files into separate sheets of an excel file. I want to create one sheet per CSV file and I would like to delete the sheets if they are already present before copying over the new data (this Part seems to work fine).

Unfortunately my script doesn't seem to copy the data. The script runs without giving me an error but there still is no data in the respective tables.
Leaving out the last bit that deletes the established connection doesn't change anything.

Thank you so much in advance.

The sheet "import" looks like this:

```
ColumnA           ColumnB
file_name         sheet_name

<pathTo>\1.csv    file_1
<pathTo>\2.csv    file_2
<pathTo>\3.csv    file_3
<pathTo>\4.csv    file_4
```

My Macro looks like this:

```
Sub AddAllFiles()
    Dim inputRow As Integer
    For inputRow = 3 To 20
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim outputSheet As String

        fileName = Sheets("import").Range("A" & inputRow).Value
        outputSheet = Sheets("import").Range("B" & inputRow).Value

        Dim checkSheetName As String
        On Error Resume Next
        checkSheetName = Worksheets(outputSheet).Name
        If checkSheetName <> "" Then
            Sheets(outputSheet).Delete
        End If
        Worksheets.Add.Name = outputSheet

        With Sheets(outputSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT" & fileName, Destination:=Sheets(outputSheet).Range("$A$1"))
            .FieldName = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePlatform = 65001
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        End With

        Dim wb_connection As WorkbookConnection
        For Each wb_connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
            If InStr(fileName, wb_connection) > 0 Then
                wb_connection.Delete
            End If
        Next wb_connection

    Next inputRow

    MsgBox "Imported CSV Files"

End Sub
```

Comment: you're missing a `;` after `"TEXT"` aren't you? i.e. `"TEXT;"` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.QueryTables.Add

Comment: Ah, you're right. However that didn't fix my problem. I after another half hour of searching I found the mistake (see my posting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your setup and used the `Refresh` function. See below. I also added the semicolon to the `Connection` string.

> The Refresh method causes Microsoft Excel to connect to the data source of the QueryTable object, execute the SQL query, and return data to the range that is based on the QueryTable object. **Unless this method is called, the QueryTable object doesn't communicate with the data source.**

Therefore, the connection exists but it has not yet attempted to open connection.

Also, this method can fail. If you had left the code without the `"TEXT;"`, you may have received an error. Just something to think about. You may want to do some error handling around it.

> After the database connection is made, the SQL query is validated. If the query isn't valid, the Refresh method fails with the SQL Syntax Error exception.

```
With Sheets(outputSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fileName, Destination:=Sheets(outputSheet).Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .Name = outputSheet
    .FieldName = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True      ' This is the step I changed.
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks you for you explanation. Error handling seems to be a good idea here.

Answer (score 0):

After Semicolon to `"TEXT"` (thanks GibralterTop)

```
With Sheets(outputSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + fileName, Destination:=Sheets(outputSheet).Range("$A$1"))
```

and adding

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

right before the end of the `with`-section my problem seems to be fixed. Since I'm brand new to VBA maybe someone can enlighten me the the exact error was.